# NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 displays wrong timestamp to console

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

```
NSDate *createDate  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1376460694.103];
NSLog(@"createDate %@",createDate);
```

I am using the above code to get the current date and time,when I put break point at createDate,It shows correct time stamp value,but NSLog(@"createDate %@",createDate) statement is printing the date as 2013-08-14 06:11:34 +0000.

How to get the correct result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The date is correct. When printing to the console the description of the date is used and that uses your system locale so it applies your time zone to the date before printing.

When you want to display the time you need to use a date formatter to convert the date into a string. The important part is setting the locale / time zone that the formatter uses.

Take a read of [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-BBCBDGID).

Comment: Agreed,but I need to display this value to the label which tells the user as wrong time,The correct time is  2013-08-14 11:41:34.  I need to display this value to the label,how to do this?